# Print result as array like 1,2,3 in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to print results like 1,2,3 in codeigniter view

Tried 
 In model

```html
public function get_data($id)
{
$this->db->select('cat'); 
$this->db->where('vl_id',$id);
$q=$this->db->get('tbl_test');
return $q->result_array();
}
```

In view

```html
<?php  foreach ($chkbx as $ccs) { 

<a> <?= $ccs['cat'];?> </a>

} ?>
```

but it is giving result as

```html
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["cat"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["cat"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

I want result like 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

> Use **Group Concat** in your Query Try like following code

```
public function get_data($id)
{    
$field = 'group_concat(tbl1.cat) AS catgory';    
$this->db->select($field, FALSE);    
$this->db->from('tbl_test AS tbl1');   
$this->db->where('tbl1.vl_id', $id);  
$query = $this->db->get(); 
if($query->num_rows())
{
    return $query->result(); 
}
}
```